# Getting issue while accessing php query

Tags: php

I am getting this error when i access the file

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_field() on boolean in
>
> /home/kdcuqjap/public_html/dbhelper.php on line 78

and the code starting from line 78 is

```
            while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
                
                //get the name of the current column
                $var = $field->name; 
                
                $$var = null;
                
                //set column key and its value as a reference
                $columns[$var] = &$$var;                    
            }
```

kindly please help me on where i am making mistake
Thanks Regards

Comment: Looks like your query failed. Check what's the result of your query...

Comment: Show the code which covers where `$meta` is created, this is where your error probably is.